# what happens with member of class during erasing from vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Below there is code, which makes me confused    :

```
class Simple{

  private:
    int m_nID;

  public:
    Simple(int nID) {
     m_nID = nID;
    }

   ~Simple() {
     std::cout << "Destructing Simple " <<  m_nID << std::endl;
    }

    Simple(const Simple& other) { 
     m_nID = other.m_nID;
    };  
 };

 int main(){
    Simple Simple1(1); // allocating on stack
    Simple Simple2(2); //
    Simple Simple3(3); //
    std::vector<Simple>  m;

    m.push_back(Simple1);  //
    m.push_back(Simple2);  // copy constructor called
    m.push_back(Simple3);  //
    std::cout << "\n------ ERASING ELEMENTs FROM VECTOR-------" << std::endl;
    m.erase(m.begin()); //
    m.erase(m.begin()); // destructor called
    m.erase(m.begin()); //
    std::cout << "\n------ After ERASING ELEMENT FROM VECTOR-------" << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Why these three lines:

```
   m.erase(m.begin());
   m.erase(m.begin());
   m.erase(m.begin());
```

cause this output:

```
   Destructing Simple 3
   Destructing Simple 3
   Destructing Simple 3
```

Why m_nID is always 3 ? For each push_back copy constructor copy 1,2,3 to m_nID, so shouldn't be:

```
    Destructing Simple 1  // or 3
    Destructing Simple 2  // or 2
    Destructing Simple 3  // or 1
```

?

Comment: `m.mVector` - what's `mVector` here?

Comment: Make also copy constructor to be verbose: when pushing things into the vector, reallocation (that means copy and deletion) may happen, but here you see only deletions

Comment: @JosephMansfield, i corrected my post, thx

Comment: See here:  http://ideone.com/SQLKen  The results shown do not match your results.  Also, your code won't compile due to the mysterious `mVector`.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia And the assignment operator. (And the move constructor and move copy if he were using them.)

Comment: @JamesKanze; That will be very instructive. In fact, in this case the existence of copy deletes the move and the transfer. The assign itself is not tightened to creation / destruction, but it can explain why 3 goes everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How does `std::vector` remove the first element?  It copies all
of the elements down one (using assignment), and then destructs
the last.  Try instrumenting the copy constructor and assignment
as well, and you'll see what's happening.  (You may also see
some unexpected copies when doing the `push_back`, if the vector
has to increase its capacity.)

Answer (score 4):

When erasing the first element, only one element (the last) is destroyed. The other elements are assigned from back to front, before:

```
Initial state:     1, 2, 3
State after copy:  2, 3, 3
State after erase: 2, 3
State after copy:  3, 3
State after erase: 3
Final state:       [empty]
```

3 is always the last.

Answer (score 1):

Make your copy contructor as

```
Simple(const Simple& other) { 
     std::cout << "Copy from "<< other.m_nID << std::endl;
     m_nID = other.m_nID;
    };
```

and you will see how when pushing things into a vector deallocation and reallcoation occur, resulting in copy and destruction.

Similarly, define also the assignemnt operator:

```
Simple& operator=(const Simple& other)
{ 
    std::cout << "assign from " << other.m_nID << " to " << m_nID << std::endl;
    m_nID = other.m_nID;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: copy constructor gives:`Copy from 1,2,3`

Comment: thx for help, after some test on http://ideone.com/oqwGbV I understood how this works.

Answer (score 0):

When I run it I get (after fixing references to non existent m.mVector to simply m)

```
Destructing Simple 1
Destructing Simple 1
Destructing Simple 2
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 2
Destructing Simple 1
```

this seems to me to be demonstrating that pushing into vector shunts a lot of stuff around

Edit - added trace in copy constructor too

```
Constructing Simple 1
Constructing Simple 2
Constructing Simple 1
Destructing Simple 1
Constructing Simple 3
Constructing Simple 1
Constructing Simple 2
Destructing Simple 1
Destructing Simple 2
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 3
Destructing Simple 2
Destructing Simple 1
```

interesting that they don't balance. I am now surprised by this too - especially after Mike Seymour pointed out that the last 3 lines are the original stack version being destroyed

Comment: The last three lines are destroying the local variables, not vector elements.